# How can I convert image background pattern?

Tags: image-processing

On this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945763/how-to-convert-the-background-to-transparent) they have been proposed solutions to convert the **background color** of some image to transparent.
But sometimes the background is a **simple pattern**, like in this case:

[image: Square background pattern]

Note the **square** background pattern.

When processing images, the background does often need to be removed or changed, but firstly you need to **detect** it (i.e: change its color, or making it transparent). For example, on the above image example, I would like to **obtain**:

[image: Pattern changed to yellow]

How can I **detect/change** a specified pattern inside an image?

GUI solutions accepted.
Open source solutions preferred (free at least required).
The **simplest** solution will be preferred (I would like to avoid installing some hundreds of MB program).

> Note: I was thinking about posting this question at [Photography](http://photo.stackexchange.com)
>   StackExchange site, but I would rather say the mind of a programmer (I
>   could need to edit dozens of such images) is more close to what I
>   want. I am not an artist.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a fully developed answer, but it does go some way towards thinking about a method - maybe someone else would like to develop it...

If, as you say, your pattern is specified, you know what it is - good, aren't I? So, you could look for the *"Minimum Repeating Unit"* of your pattern in your image. In your case it is a 16x16 grid like this:

[image]

Now you can search for that pattern in your image. I am using ImageMagick at the command-line, but you can use other tools if you prefer. ImageMagick is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows for free. So, I search for that grid in your globe image and ImageMagick gives me an output image showing white dots at the top-left corner of every location where the two images match:

```
compare -metric ae -dissimilarity-threshold 1.0 -compose src -subimage-search globe.gif grid.png res.png
```

That gets me this in file `res-1.png`

[image]

Now the white dots are where the 16x16 *"Minimum Repeating Unit"* is found in the image, but at the top-left corner so I shift them right and down by 8 pixels to the centre of the matching area, then I create a new output image where each pixel is the maximum pixel of the 16x16 grid in which it existed before:

```
convert res-1.png -roll +8+8 -statistic maximum 16x16  z.png
```

[image]

I can now invert that mask and then use it to set the opacity of the original image, thereby blanking areas that matched the *"Minimum Repeating Unit"*:

```
convert globe.gif \( z.png -negate \) -compose copy_opacity -composite q.png
```

[image]

No, it's not perfect, but it is an idea for an approach that could be refined...

Comment: A very interesting idea, Mark. For common background patterns it could be worth the effort to build "remover" scripts.